# Will salesforce notify when about failed emails when TLS is unavailable?

Tags: email, force.com-sites, email-relay

We have enabled email relay in our organization. Recently our security team performed a scan of our salesforce instance and has asked us to change the TLS (Transport Layer Security) setting. Earlier it was set to "Preferred"(which I guess is default). Now we are asked to change it to "Required".

I wanted to understand the implications of doing so before we actually change the setting. I checked the documentation and it states salesforce will terminate the session if TLS is unavailable. This means email will not be sent. Will salesforce notify us in such cases? Or Is there any setting to be enabled by which we can get notified.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR - Yes, Salesforce will log emails that fail as a result of TLS being unavailable; this includes if TLS is unavailable is a result of "Required" being selected in the TLS setting and the outbound server failing to support TLS.**

---

First, might be worth quoting Salesforce's email deliverability setting docs you're referencing:

> **To configure the email deliverability settings for your organization:**
>
> [...]
>
> 9. To specify how Salesforce uses the Transport Layer Security (TLS) protocol for secure email communication for SMTP sessions, choose one
>      of the following:
>
> **Required Verify:** Salesforce continues the session only if the remote
>   server offers TLS, the certificate is signed by a valid certificate
>   authority, and the common name presented in the certificate matches
>   the domain or mail exchange to which Salesforce is connected. If any
>   of these criteria are not met, Salesforce terminates the session
>   without delivering the email.
>
> **Note:** If you select a setting other than Preferred (the default setting),
>   select Restrict TLS to these domains and specify a comma-separated
>   domain list. The asterisk (*) wildcard is allowed; for example,
>   *.subdomains.com matches john@aco.subdomains.com and john@bco.subdomains.com (but not john@subdomains.com). If you don't
>   specify domains, Salesforce uses the TLS setting you specify for all
>   outbound emails, which may result in emails not being delivered.
>
> **Important:** If you plan to use Transport Layer Security (TLS) with this connection, enter the host name instead of the IP address. TLS
>   requires the host name for verifying certificates
>
> ([source-1](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=emailadmin_deliverability.htm), [source-2](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=email_relay.htm&language=en_US))

Next what you're looking is to know if Salesforce will log the failure in a way that you're able to tell the failure was a result of TLS connection failure. Salesforce logs this is the `EmailBouncedReason` field, which is within the [Contact](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm) & [Lead](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm) objects.

Next you need to know the email delivery code for a TLS connection error, here's the list of [Salesforce's Mail None Delivery (NDR) codes](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005053&language=en_US) & [Pardot's Bounce Codes](http://www.pardot.com/faqs/emails/bounce-codes/); Pardot was acquired by Salesforce when it acquired ExactTarget. You'll notice that none of these code explicitly list TLS failure as an explanation, but it appears likely that a failure would be coded as "[451 The command has been aborted due to a server error. Not your fault.](https://support.google.com/postini/answer/134416?hl=en)"

To get a report of the contacts that bounced, see "[How can I get a list of contacts whose email message bounced?](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h3P7AAI)"

If you want to confirm this, you'll have to setup or find a external system were TLS is not supported, but were the service is valid; which you can check using free online tools like [CheckTLS](http://checktls.com/perl/TestSender.pl) or [SSL-Tools](https://ssl-tools.net/mailservers/stackexchange.com).  If possible, given security made the request, beyond you confirm that you "checked a box" - ask them if they will supply a way to confirm Salesforce is really enforcing that "checked a box" - since it's always possible they're not (aka "[goto fail](http://avandeursen.com/2014/02/22/gotofail-security/)").

---

**UPDATES:**

- Also of note, appears I was correct that there's the [potential for Salesforce implementation to either be dated, flawed, etc](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/33020/7651); say this since it appears the code referenced in the question `451 4.7.5 [internal] tls negotiation failed` was an inbound response from another mail server saying Salesforce did not have support for 256bit ciphers; also, this appears to be a [custom code generated by the Symantec Messaging Gateway](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH215003).